# ASP: How to use a single span or div element to display validation errors

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-validators

I have a field that required 3 different validators:
`RequiredFieldValidator`, `RegularExpressionValidator`, and `CompareValidator`.

Each validator has a "*" to show that something is wrong with the input:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMin" runat="server" Width="30%" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="Min Value is missing" ControlToValidate="txtAddMin" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Min Value Entered" ControlToValidate="txtAddMin" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{2}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddMin" ControlToCompare="txtAddMax" Operator="LessThan" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Min Value shoule be less then MaxValue" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="vgBinAdd">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Validations work as expected, however, when failing, the "*" is displayed in different positions. So, when `CompareValidator` fails, the "*" is displayed a few spaces from the input field.

Basically, every validator takes up some space after the input field and "*" is displayed with extra space before it based which validator fails.

IS that possible to fix that, so, the start is displayed in the fix position no matter which validator fails?

Comment: Wrap all three validators by `span` with `position:relative` and set `position:absolute` to the validators (using CSS classes, of course).

Comment: I did that. Now, the "*" is on the same position, but it moved a little bit higher then usual

Comment: position it using `top:2px` or whatever

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I noticed another thing. When I enter characters into the "txtAddMin" field, `comparevalidator` is firing off the message saying "Min Value should be less then Max Value". But I really was expecting `comparevalidator` to validate numeric field only

Comment: Create `customvalidator` instead of your three and do all validation in it.